# Is GET better than POST in AJAX approach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

I'm wondering, why are we still using GET method in AJAX requests for example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "SomeController/GetSomething",
  data: { id: 100}
});
```

GET is handy, when you want to store data in url, when you are querying Google and you want to send that query to friend or whatever else. On the other hand, we have security gaps. They are not big (I'd say they are obstacles), but it'd be slightly better to use POST when you don't want to show form data. Moreover, POST can store any type of data, control data size and hide somehow passing variables.

Is it a good solution to always use GET in places, which are not "public" (search bars, article page, user profile, ...) and use POST everywhere else? With this approach, all AJAX queries should be send using POST method.

Comment: GET means you can see parameters in the URL; not so w/ POST.  GET has a max length limit (server dependent: 2KB-8KB); not so w/ POST.

Comment: the difference is not in how you use it, but how they SHOULD be used: GET = give me 'something' with id 100. POST = create something with id 100. This is mostly meant for RESTful services though. The other reason is you can copy a GET request, not a POST request.

Comment: Of course, it's REST.

Comment: i hit enter too early... added to my comment :-)

Comment: GET must be little bit faster compared to POST, while there is no sensitive data passed

Answer (score 1):

When using `POST` XHR, you use a two-step process : sending the headers first and then the data, but you use Ajax for responsiveness, right ? So why use a two-step process when you can use a one-step process (`GET` XHR)?

Furthermore, AFAIK, `GET` request are cacheable, `POST` are not.

Last but not least, as some have pointed : HTTP verbs do have a meaning.

Keep on using `GET` XHR for getting datafrom server, and `POST` XHR for sending data.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, GET is not secure but it allows us to copy and paste links and get the same results. POST  is more secure in the way it does not show the parameters directly, it still needs work on the backend to plug all the holes.

Answer (score 0):

The key is not to forget why one is called "GET" and the other one "POST".

GET is accessible, so not good for anything sensitive, but easy to manipulate directly.

POST should be used to submit to the server side, sensitive or "lengthy" data.

Answer (score 0):

This is only my opinion:

A savvy user who really wants to know what data is being posted will always be able to discover exactly  what data is being transmitted during an http request.  The only tool that you really need for this are the tools that are built into modern browsers.  If you transmit using HTTPS, then a third party will be able to discern GET parameters, but not POST data, so I would say you are correct that sensitive data should only be sent as POST.  Otherwise, as a security tool, POST over GET serves a similar function to a password mask on password inputs (prevent someone from looking at your data over your shoulder).

Now, to your question "Is GET better...?"

I would say that just like with synchronous http requests, you should use GET when the user or your application need to *get* data, and POST when your app of the user needs to *post* data (for persistence - in the session (like a login), or a database, etc).  So it's really more of a semantic difference.  Practically, you could use post for everything if you wanted to.